# Nested PRINT in CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, printing, triggers, case

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Persons_Update_CASE]
   ON [dbo].[Persons]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Persons SET
        FirstName    = (CASE WHEN D.FirstName <> I.FirstName THEN I.FirstName END),
        LastName = (CASE WHEN D.LastName <> I.LastName THEN I.LastName END),        
        ID_Titlu = (CASE WHEN D.ID_Titlu <> I.ID_Titlu THEN I.ID_Titlu END)             

    FROM DELETED AS D
        INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON D.Person_ID=I.Person_ID


END
```

I am trying to create a trigger that updates only the columns modified. I would like to print a statements for each CASE branch in order to observe which one has been executed. Can anyone help me?

I also tried this, but i get multiple errors `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tr_Persoane_Update_Elegant, Line 10` on lines 10,17,26,34.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Persons_Update_Elegant]
   ON [dbo].[Persons]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  D.FirstName, D.LastName, D.ID_Titlu, I.FirstName, I.LastName, I.ID_Titlu,
            CASE WHEN D.FirstName <> I.FirstName
                    THEN
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE Persons
                            SET  FirstName = I.FirstName
                            WHERE FirstName = D.FirstName
                            PRINT 'FirstName  has been changed'
                        END
            /*END                       
            CASE*/ WHEN D.LastName <> I.LastName
                    THEN
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE Persons
                            SET  LastName = I.LastName
                            WHERE LastName = D.LastName
                            PRINT 'LastName has been changed'
                        END 
            /*END                       
            CASE*/ WHEN D.Title_ID <>   I.Title_ID
                    THEN
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE Persons
                            SET Title_ID=I.Title_ID
                            WHERE Title_ID=D.Title_ID
                        END
            END
    FROM DELETED AS D
        INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON D.ID_Person=I.ID_Person                     

END
```

Comment: You could try to invert the flow i.e. check the condition first then do the update and print.

Comment: Another thing - are you trying to update the `Persons` table in your trigger? Or did you mean to include some other table?

Comment: I am trying to update the Persons. I have an application in which the users can change a Person's attributes. I want to have a single stored procedure to take arguments for all columns, but only the ones that contain a different value to be updated, hence the trigger.

Comment: I edited my original post with my attempt of an inverted flow. It must be somthing I'm missing in the CASE statement syntax.

Comment: How many other columns are there in the table? Can you post the table definiton of `dbo.Persons`?

Comment: @DMason These are the columns in table dbo.Persons      Person_ID(PK,autoincrement),FirstName,LastName,Title_ID